# Counting rows in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This function counts songs for specified album using PDO.

I tried looking at what's wrong but nothing.
searched here and bing, nothing.

```
function artist_count_songs($id) {
    global $db;
    $count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`song_id`) FROM `songs` WHERE `album_id` = :id");
    $count = $count->execute(array(':id' => $id));        
    echo $count;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?
tried rowcolumn still nothing

Database structure

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `songs` (
  `song_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `download_url` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`song_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `songs` (`song_id`, `album_id`, `name`, `download_url`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'بحبك اه', 'downloads/tamerhosny/b7bk-ah.mp3'),
(2, 1, 'بحبك اه', 'downloads/tamerhosny/b7bk-ah.mp3');
```

EDIT 1

```
    // Count songs total for album
    function artist_count_songs($album_id) {
        global $db;        
        $stmt    = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`song_id`) FROM `songs` WHERE `album_id` = :album_id");
        $success = $stmt->execute(array(':album_id' => $album_id));
        list($count) = $stmt->fetch();
        echo '<th>';
        echo $count;
        echo '</th>';
    }
```

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
You need to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Do not re-use variable names. It's not expensive or so to use two variables here instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$count` is actually a boolean that is the return value of the `execute` method.

```
$stmt    = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT COUNT(`song_id`) FROM `songs` WHERE `album_id` = :id"
);
var_dump($stmt);

$success = $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
var_dump($success);

list($count) = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($count);
```

Comment: Its thorwing out this error...
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\music\functions.php on line 7